# Microsip softphone build problem (cannot open file 'hid.lib')

Tags: voip, pjsip

I am going to build microsip softphone from www.microsip.org, which is based on pjsip project.
The pjsip project files are downloaded and built successfully.
but when I build microsip source I get the following error :

cannot open file 'hid.lib'

I use VS2017 and this file is specified in linker dependencies.
I don't know what is this lib and how can I get the file or compile any other source to get it.

if anybody has experience working with microsip and it's dependencied please help.

Comment: so have you managed to compile microsip successfully ?  if so please write tutorial on how to do this

Answer (score 2):

1) Install "Microsoft Windows Driver Kit"

2) Project -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories. Set location of `hid.lib` (for me it's at `C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\i386`)